# How to use a string as an operator?

Tags: perl

It is possible to use a string as an operator?

```
my $ip = "10 > 0.2 && 5 < 1";
if($ip)
{
    print "Hello\n\n";
}
else 
{
    print "wrong\n";
}
```

How to consider the string `> && <` as an operator?

Comment: You're asking to evaluate the string as Perl code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A non-empty string will always evaluate to true if you use it like this. What you want to do is to evaluate the content of the string as code, and perl provides the [eval-statement](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) for exactly this purpose:

```
my $ip = "10 > 0.2 && 5 < 1";
if( eval($ip) ) 
{
    print "Hello \n\n";
}
else  
{
    print "wrong\n";
}
```

This will give the expected output "wrong".

Comment: Also, beware of where the string comes from. Executing as `eval` some user-defined expression can be dangerous.

Comment: Minor point of pedantry:  In addition to empty strings, the string '0' also evaluates as false.